# PHP tidy up relative url / up one level

Tags: php, wordpress, url, relative-path

On my Wordpress site I've moved my uploads directory and everything is working correctly, but the URLs to images and attachments just look a bit ugly:

eg `http://<website>/wordpress/../media/uploads/2013/09/<image>.jpg`

I'd like to tidy up the "up one level" part of the URL, so it looks something like this, `http://<website>/media/uploads/2013/09/<image>.jpg`, instead.

Anyone know of a nice PHP function to tidy the URLs?

Comment: http://<website>/wordpress/../media/ means http://<website>/media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the following in the `functions.php` file in your theme folder:

```
function canonicalize($address)
{
    $address = explode('/', $address);
    $keys = array_keys($address, '..');

    foreach($keys AS $keypos => $key)
    {
        array_splice($address, $key - ($keypos * 2 + 1), 2);
    }

    $address = implode('/', $address);
    $address = str_replace('./', '', $address);
}
```

to be able to do something like:

```
echo canonicalize('http://www.example.com/something/../else''); 
//http://www.example.com/else
```

from http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.realpath.php#71334

Comment: Thank you! I did look through the PHP realpath documentation but unfortunately not at the comments.